# In tensorflow V.2 Astroid error during TensorFlow installation and AttributeError: module tensorflow has no attribute Session

Tags: tensorflow

anaconda3.7버전을 다운받고 tensorfow gpu버전을 다운 받았습니다(그 전에 CUDA v.10,cuDNN도 다운 받았어요.)

그런데 tensorflow설치 과정에서 에러가 하나 발생했네요.

```
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
```

위 문제가 중요한가요? 중요하다면 어떻게 해결할 수 있나요?

그리고 jupyter notebook과 Ipython에서 다음과 같이 입력했는데요.

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello=tf.constant('Hello,Tensorflow')
sess=tf.Session()
```

다음과 같은 오류가 떴어요.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0f0f12c24d95> in <module>
----> 1 sess=tf.Session()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

어떻게 해결해야 하나요?

Answer (score 0):

In tf2, get get session with the compatible interface.

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

Comment: I chagend
sess=tf.Session()
to sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
but there is a problem like this
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v1'